# How to change onsubmit function to onchange function on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

How change the onsubmit function to onchange function on the code below. How to display the difference of days on the spot once after we click the second date without clicking the submit button?

thank you

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script> 
function dateDiff(dateform) {
date1 = new Date();
date2 = new Date();
diff  = new Date();

date1temp = new Date(dateform.firstdate.value);
date1.setTime(date1temp.getTime());

date2temp = new Date(dateform.seconddate.value);
date2.setTime(date2temp.getTime());
diff.setTime(Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()));

timediff = diff.getTime();
days = Math.floor(timediff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)+ 1); 
dateform.difference.value = days;
return false; 
}
</script>
</head>
<form onSubmit="return dateDiff(this);">
<pre>
First Date(MM/DD/YYYY):     <input type=date name=firstdate>   

Second Date(MM/DD/YYYY):    <input type=date name=seconddate> 

Date Difference (in days):  <input type=text name=difference>

                        <input type=submit value="Calculate Difference!">

</pre>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: post your code please

Comment: provide code so that we can help.

Comment: Showing us a little bit of code would be great.

Comment: just google it.. you got plenty of links to do it.

Comment: sorry, i just realize the code doesnt appears on my question huhuhu. here you go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply give form an id `<form onSubmit="return dateDiff(this);" id="myfrm">`

Assign a change handler on date fields and call your function passing your form

```
<script>
  var fd = document.querySelector("[name=firstdate]");
  var sd = document.querySelector("[name=seconddate]");
  var fm = document.querySelector("#myfrm");

  fd.addEventListener('change',function(){ return dateDiff(fm); } );
  sd.addEventListener('change',function(){ return dateDiff(fm); } );
</script>
```

Comment: still dont get it sir. can you show on my code? thank you

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/934zterr/) also take care of `<pre>` tags

Comment: If you get *fm* first, then `fd = fm.firstdate` and `sd = fm.seconddate`, which is a little less to type. ;-)